# "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server" after more than 100 emails

Tags: laravel, gmail

I'm trying to send about 500 emails with Laravel, my provider is Gmail.
The first 150 emails (more or less) are sent correctly, but after I receive this error:

`"Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "XXXXXXX" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response."`

My .env is

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_USERNAME=...
MAIL_PASSWORD=...
```

I also tried to wait for about 5 seconds between each email, but it doesn't work.
Anyone knows how I can handle this?

Thank you

Comment: More likely the per day email limit is 100-150. [unofficial article](https://group-mail.com/sending-email/email-send-limits-and-options/). Either go for business suite or You can move to a service like Amazon SES which supports 200 emails per day. You can increase the limit with a simple request supporting your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the next settings:
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

Enable 2FA in your Google account and create an app password.
Use it in MAIL_PASSWORD

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and here is how I solved it.
the Google mail service may have blocked emails from being sent from your app. Google surely viewed this as a security threat. you should definitely receive a security alert in your mailbox.

You just have to admit that it was you who tried to access the account or just change your gmail password. after that please change the info in the .env file and i think it will work.

- try to change your password on gmail
- and also in your .env file